# How to save RTF files in "MS Word style" without MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, rtf

In Helios application we are using .RTF documents saved in Microsoft Word.

Microsoft Word is saving RTF files differently then any other app.

- E.g. **294 kB** file (saved in LibreOffice Writer) has **17504 kB** (saved in MS Word).

Unfortunatelly these smaller RTF files ruin formatting and some warning is popped up: "InvalidRTFHeader". So it looks like Helios (which is old proprietary app) needs this bloat.

As extern worker I don't own MS Office. Is there any way how to save RTF files in "MS Word" way without MS Word?

I tried LibreOffice Writer, Google docs and even Microsoft 365 Online, but everything saves RTF file "normally" - so not that big as MS Word.

Comment: What's in the MS-Word saves may be implementing functionality not available in whatever you're using. If your application can generate RTF files that Word can use, why do you need the additional bloat?

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround: Windows (v. 95 through 11, at least) ships with [*WordPad*](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/wordpad-windows-10) installed, which can save documents in Rich Text Format (RTF). That might, or might not, meet the needs of *Helios*. WordPad on Win10 is at `%ProgramFiles%\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe`.

You can also open a RTF file in a pure *text* editor, such as [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/), and see what differences are in the MS *Word* file as opposed to that saved otherwise, or compare the two documents with a tool such as [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/?lang=en). Does *Word* include font information missing from other RTF files? Does it use XML markup? See Wikipedia for [notes on the RTF specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format).

Comment: WordPad ruins formatting immediatelly after opening file. I tried to compare it in WinMerge, but it is completly different. Different formatting, Word includes every font information (even those, that are not in document used) and big bloat (010101...)